# How does JitPack handle subdirectories?

Tags: jitpack

I have in the past successfully used JitPack to import dependencies directly from their Git repos, having them built on the fly if necessary. Just add JitPack as a repository and replace the group ID with something à la `com.gitlab.username` (reverse DNS name of the git provider followed by username), the artifact ID with the repo name and the version with a valid git ref.

All of the repositories I have used, however, contain just the code for a single jar, with one single `pom.xml` in the root dir.

Now I am wondering if and how JitPack can handle more complex repos—specifically, a repo which has a back-end library and a front-end app in separate subdirectories.

The repo has two subdirs, `frontend` and `backend`, each with their own `pom.xml`. The `pom.xml` in the root dir essentially tells Maven to build the two subdirs. (Or maybe it uses Gradle and has `build.gradle` in place of `pom.xml`.)

Now I would like to include the library in `backend` in a different project. Can I do this with JitPack? If so, since the group and artifact ID will give JitPack just the repo, how can I tell it to build a particular subdir of that repo?